# Get the amount of commits published on a GitHub repository with Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, github, discord.js

I have a simple GitHub command, that only displays some links to some pages on my repository. But I want to upgrade it. Is it possible to get the total amount of commits of a GH repo? And is there other data you can pull (contributors, files changed, latest version etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a GET request to the GitHub rest api at the endpoint: api.github.com/repos/{owner}/{repo}/commits

Where the owner is the username of the owner of the repository, and the repo is the name of the repository. Using any library of choice to make HTTP requests will allow you to fetch a list of the repos, which of course you can take the length of to find the number of commits.

[See GitHub docs here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/commits#list-commits) and,

[See guide to using a rest api on discordjs](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/rest-api.html#making-http-requests-with-node)

Edit: To get the rest of the information you listed, I'd recommend consulting the [full list of rest api endpoints for GitHub apps.](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/endpoints-available-for-github-apps)

Comment: Your GET request worked, but only with a public repository. Is there also a way with private repo's? And what do you mean with HTTP requests? I am not very experienced with Javascript. So can you please give me some more information?